# Overlay permission to read text on screen with user action

Tags: android, ios, screen-readers

I am building keyboard app that will have screen reading button. when *user clicks* on it will ***read text from screen*** from any app and copy to clipboard. I want to know is that possible to get with overlay permission?

I tried to apply screen reading permission but ios doesn't accept it so i want to try overlay permission.

Comment: For overlay permissions on Android, you may need the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission. iOS on the other hand does not have a direct equivalent to Android's overlay permission. Apps on iOS operate within a sandboxed environment.

Comment: In Android, all `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` does is allow you to draw a window over the screen. It does not allow you to obtain any content from the screen.